# Is there an invisible wall above a certain building in the Metro Kingdom?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In the Metro Kingdom, there is a small area in which you ride a motor scooter with a dinosaur chasing you.  The "Motor Scooter: Escape!" and "Big Jump: Escape!" Power Moons are located here.  At the end of this section, there is a jump, where the dinosaur falls into a pit while you escape.  After this jump, the third building on the left wall is short enough that you could feasibly reach it with a well-timed jump off of the scooter.

I have tried to make it to the top of this building many times, since there are often secrets in places like this in the game.  Specifically, I was looking for Power Moons and Purple Coins.  I have not been able to land the jump, or grab the ledge, even when the scooter is right next to this building, at the same height as the roof.

In my last attempt, it looked to me like I was wall-sliding down the empty space above this building!  Is there an invisible wall there, or was I mistaken in what I was seeing?  I'd much rather not waste any more time on something impossible.

Comment: I'm sure there isn't a moon there because little challenge areas like that always contain either one or two moons, never three.

Comment: @Pyritie that was my instinct as well, but it was also the first time I've seen somewhere in the game that was low enough to reach but still seems impossible to get to

Comment: Always go back in those side areas, cappy will tell you if there is still something to find.

Comment: @Fredy31 is that a post-game change?  I haven't noticed that yet in my game, though I'm usually pretty good at getting everything the first time through.

Comment: I dont know, I think I remember seeing it before beating everything. If you havent beaten it yet try it! When you go to a secret area, after beating it, run back in. Cappie will say something like 'I have a feeling we havent seen everything' or 'There's nothing else for us to do here depending if there is still Moons/Coins in that zone

Comment: @Kokiomot The hints start showing up after you break the moon rock in the kingdom.

Comment: @Pyritie There are always two moons per sub-area: One that is the clear goal, and one that is a side objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, there is an invisible wall at that location.**

A recent [video posted on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/7a6noi/in_mario_odyssey_you_can_go_anywhere_you_wa/) clearly shows Mario wall sliding, then diving into an invisible wall above the building in question.

Also, as Fredy31 suggested in the comments, I have returned to the area (after completing the main story) and Cappy confirmed that there is nothing else to find in the area, so there can be no Power Moons or Purple Coins above that building.